# Including bootstrap.min.css but glyphicon-star not working

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded bootstrap.min.css from bootswatch superhero and I do this in my index.html head element:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

but the glyphicon-star is not working.
So if in my directive js file I have:

```
template: '<span ng-repeat="star in vm.stars track by $index" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star">{{ star }}</span>',
```

nothing shows, whereas if I do something very basic such as:

```
template: '<ul> <li ng-repeat="star in vm.stars track by $index" >{{ star }}</li></ul>'
```

I do see the bullets of the list items. vm.stars is an array with a length of 1 to 5.
Why are the glyphs not showing? Does it depend on the version of bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: Are you able to successfully use any glyphicons at all in your application?

Comment: Probably not, I was missing the fonts directory so it could not work. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to download the full bootstrap and replace the bootstrap.min.css downloaded from bootswatch/superhero by the one in the bootstrap distribution (I chose 3.3.7).
If you open the bootstrap.min.css and you search for glyph, there are matches, whereas there are none in the bootstrap.min.css from bootswatch/superhero.
Another thing is to copy the fonts directory from the bootstrap zip to the public directory of my AngularJS application.
This solves the problem, now I see the stars.